# Why does Apple use entitlements?

Tags: ios, xcode, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I know what entitlements are, but why does Apple use this process? I was just wondering if anyone knew this as this explanation is not easy to find when conducting an online search...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entitlements confer specific capabilities or security permissions to your iOS or macOS app. Try to read this https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html :)